# Next JS Images after next build gives 404 images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

Default URL structure is http://localhost:5000/_next/image?url="someURL".

I want the URL to be like **http://localhost:5000/demo/_next/image?url="someURL".**

which can be achieved by

```
// next.config.js
     images: {
            domains: ['example.domain.com'],
            path: `/demo/_next/image`
        },
```

In this, the **_next/image** where the directory is pointing cannot be found.

After this, all the images are giving 404. I need a solution to this problem in the next js.

Comment: `path` is meant to be used to add a prefix when using a [cloud provider for the image optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader), it won't change the path where your images are optimized by Next.js.

Comment: @juliomalves yes you are correct, my problem is after I build the next JS project. I don't want the next js-Image default optimization that has a path like this (http://localhost:5000/_next/image?url="some URL".).Immediately after the localhost.I want it to happen with my url prefix (http://localhost:5000/demo/_next/image).

Comment: @juliomalves because of this problem.I used the path in images.Since  assets prefix: '/demo/' did not work for images.Due to this am not able to attain the Image optimization beneits that next js provides.

Comment: Have you tried using [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath)? It would change the path for all files though, not just the images.

Comment: @juliomalves yes basePath adds, but the resulting image gives 404. Because next js demo/_next/image is not routed anywhere in my node js server.
I don't know which folder its routing  _next/image path routing it. I routed it to the .next folder but it dint work in my case

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a middleware to rewrite those routes to the correct location?

Something like:
`pages/_middleware.ts` with content:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req: NextRequest): NextResponse {
  if (req.nextUrl.href.includes('/demo/_next/image'))
    return NextResponse.rewrite(
      req.nextUrl.href.replace('/demo/_next/image', '/_next/image'),
    );

  return null;
}
```